# Greater than > Less than < inside thymeleaf javascript... Error: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup

Tags: java, javascript, html, spring, thymeleaf

I get this error when I try to insert `<` or `>` operators inside the `thymeleaf` javascript.

My code

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        ...
        if(timeRemain < 0){
            ...
        }
        ...
        var result = (hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours) + ":" + (minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes) + ":" + (seconds  < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds);
        ...         
    });
</script>
```

Error message

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.

How can i solve this?

Comment: It's fine to ask and answer your own question in general, but when the information you're providing is [right there, very clearly (not remotely hidden away) in the documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#script-inlining-javascript-and-dart), there's no purpose to having the question/answer on SO.

Comment: Well even though you mentioned that there is no purpose, this question have served more than 1k views with few thumbs up. I'm happy about that, as this post is helping developers in some way.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This issue is solved by adding `CDATA` to the `script` tag as below

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    ...  
    ...
    ...
    /*]]>*/
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from using CDATA you can also encode `< as &lt;` and `> as  &gt;`

Comment: Thank you. But I just tired and it gives this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;` in the console.

Comment: I did it like this `var result = (hours &gt; 10 ? "0" + hours : hours)...` without the `CDATA`